# Как добавлять в Unity сторонние библиотеки

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Встала задача в Unity взаимодействовать с instagram API, решено было не изобретать велосипед и использовать готовые решения. Нашел 2 библиотеки одна
https://github.com/vespassassina/.NET-Instagram-API-Wrapper
https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp
Вторая отсеклась из за необходимости поддержки .net версий выше чем 2.0 (В Unity к сожалению пока только она, поддержка 4.6 вроде обещается в релизе в ноябре).
Выбрал первую библиотеку но к сожалению не понял как правильно импортировать ее в Unity проект.

Я попытался сделать так: скачал репозиторий и положил его в папку assets в unity, далее в visual studio добавил к текущему солюшену (который создает unity) 2 существующих проекта этой библиотеки, и из основно проекта добавил ссылки путем клика ПКМ на проект=>добавить ссылку => и указал 2 проекта этой библиотеки, в visual studio все выглядит нормально, подключаются using apibase и using instagram.api; 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но при этом при переключении в Unity висят ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос как правильно добавить библиотеку в проект?

**UPDATE**
При включении выключении visual студии выглядит так что ссылки на 2 добавленных проект отваливаются словно Unity как то модифицирует решение.

Либо я совсем все делаю не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как юнити использует свой компилятор, студия используется только как текстовый редактор и средство отладки, не более.

Если вы подключаете `dll`, то вам нужно просто положить ее в папку `Plugins` (не обязательно, просто так удобнее). Если вы подключаете библиотеку из исходников, то просто кладете код в папку на ваше усмотрение и используете.

Вы так же можете собрать динамически подключаемую библиотеку (`dll`) из исходников сами, используя, к примеру, Visual Studio.

Что касается первой библиотеки, возможно, она устарела? Ей же 5 лет...

Comment: буду надеяться что не устарела :) Если других ответов не поступит отмечу ваше как правильный. Я правильно понимаю что я могу скомпилить первую либу в DLL и подложить в папку plugins и использовать ее?

Comment: Кстати, класть в папку `Plugins` не обязательно, просто так нагляднее. А еще: если лицензия позволяет, можно просто переписать те места, которые не компилируются для старых .net. Это один из минусов своего компилятора в unity, вы же понимаете, что поддерживать компиляцию c# под столько платформ весьма сложно)

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в ответ что при необходимости можно собрать из исходников DLL библиотеку и использовать её. Думаю для многих новичков это окажется полезным, как оказалось полезным мне :) и я отмечу уже тогда ответ как верный. Ну а как собрать библиотеку думаю люди уже разберутся )))

Comment: спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Еще небольшой вопрос если можно, я так понимаю по той же причине что студия просто как редактор используется то подружить unity и nuget можно и не мечтать?

Comment: Я не pro конкретно в c#, но так как nuget - это система сборки (как я понимаю - что-то вроде gradle, maven, npm и пр.), то в этом ведь нет смысла? Unity позволяет писать Editor-скрипты, которые могут частично заменить сборщик.

Comment: Как подключить UnityEngine.Advertisements? Я думал что это стандартная либа, которая должна сама подтягиваться.